# unable to run docker container using marathon

Tags: docker, containers, mesos, marathon

I am trying to run docker container using apache marathon/mesos. In the official documentation they have mentioned `echo "docker,mesos" > /etc/mesos-slave/containerizers` should be done to use docker.

But there is no such file or directory on my machine. I'm using ubuntu 14.04. my mesos version is 0.22.1. It only shows deploying while running using marathon using `--containerizer==docker,mesos` flag.

For this flag to work I need to do that echo thing. But there is no such thing on my machine.

Comment: That command will create the file, just try running it and continuing with the tutorial.

Comment: Not sure what setup you use, this file should exist only on Agent (slaves) machines.

Comment: My slave and the master are same machine. I couldn't find such file or directory. Without that file/directory I can't continue. Is it okay if I manually create that file?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it should be

> echo "docker,mesos" > /etc/mesos-slave/containerizers

Comment: I see you changed it in the question above, but don't forget the 's' at the end.

Comment: thanks, I've changed it. Do you know how to fix this.

Comment: Well, the containerizers fie should translate to a flag of the mesos-slave process:  `/usr/sbin/mesos-slave --master=zk://1.2.3.4:2181/mesos --log_dir=/var/log/mesos --containerizers=docker,mesos 
--hostname=1.2.3.4`. Is there an error logged in /var/log/mesos/mesos-master.ERROR?

Comment: I've installed mesos in my home directory i.e mesos directory is there in my home directory. No, my log files are not showing any errors. I'm using `./bin/mesos-slave.sh --log_dir==/home/file-path --containerizers=docker,mesos --master=127.0.0.1:5050` to start slave.

Comment: So where exactly does it go wrong? Do you see mesos and marathon interfaces at ports 5050 and 8080? Can you post a .json to marathon? What does the .json look like?

Comment: yes, I'm able to see the mesos and marathon interfaces. But when I post a .json file, it's showing deploying for hours and it's not getting deployed. So, I thought may be it's due to --containerizers flag as I don't have that containerizers file.

Comment: If the containerizers flag is in your process list, than it should work. In any case the log files should tell you what's happening. Probably the Mesos interface will show you a bunch of failed tasks? If so, check the stdout/stderr of those.

Comment: Maybe the answer is in the json. Perhaps you are requesting resources (ports, cpu, mem) that are not available?

Comment: I'm trying to deploy A Simple docker-based application(basic-3) in this link
https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/application-basics.html

Comment: Does the user running Mesos have permissions to run docker? Can the docker daemon reach the docker hub for pulling the image?

Comment: yes, I'm able to pull an image if I directly write `"cmd":"docker pull xxx/image"`. While trying the other way, it's only showing delpoying for hours.

Comment: logs of the containers should be under `/tmp/mesos/slaves/[id]/frameworks/[id]/executors/[id]/runs/[id]/` and would be called `stdout` and `stderr`. You should be able to find more info there.